# rigidbody.force assign attempt for 'Player' is not valid. Input force is { NaN, NaN, NaN }. UnityEngine.Rigidbody:AddForce(Vector3)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working an a game with planets, so I decided to add gravity to my planets. I've been following a video on YouTube where a guy has been guiding me through the whole process. The script works for a simple sphere/planet but it doesn't work on my Player, then I get the error 
"rigidbody.force assign attempt for 'Player' is not valid. Input force is `{ NaN, NaN, NaN }.` `UnityEngine.Rigidbody:AddForce(Vector3)"`

The Player do have a movement script attached.

Well here is my script

```
public class Attractor : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Rigidbody rb;

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Attractor[] attractors = FindObjectsOfType<Attractor>();
        foreach (Attractor attractor in attractors)
        {
            if(attractor != this)
                Attract(attractor);
        }
    }

    void Attract (Attractor objToAttract)
    {
        Rigidbody rbToAttract = objToAttract.rb;

        Vector3 direction = rb.position - rbToAttract.position;
        float distance = direction.magnitude;

        float forceMagnitude = (rb.mass * rbToAttract.mass) / Mathf.Pow(distance, 2);
        Vector3 force = direction.normalized * forceMagnitude;

        rbToAttract.AddForce(force);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the huge distance divided your *forceMagnitude* by a number that is too small.

I'd recommend skipping the attraction process if the distance is too great.
Or you could try clamping your distance to a maximum and a minimum value.

Cheers.

Comment: This makes sense to me, NaN implies that the values are outside the float range (i.e. too many decimal points to retrieve proper accuracy)